# Qt - How to create a QFuture from a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, async-await, future

I am currently working on an editor program; there's a feature I need to write, which requires loading several files in a row using the project's asynchronous file API, then performing some more computations once those files are loaded.

In another language, this would probably be implemented with an async/await workflow, eg:

```
let firstFile = await FileAPI.loadFile("Foo.xxx", ...);
let otherFile = await FileAPI.loadFile("Bar/Foobar.xxx", ...);
```

The Qt equivalent to this code would be to spawn a new thread using `QtConcurrent::run`, returning a QFuture, and waiting for that future to yield a result.

However, in the project I work on, the file-opening API runs on a single worker thread, **which means I can't use `QtConcurrent::run`**. This is **an established, non-negotiable part of the codebase**. Eg the constructor of the file API looks like:

```
FileApiWorker* worker = new FileApiWorker();
m_workerThread = new QThread();
worker->moveToThread( m_workerThread );

// Input signals
connect( this, &FileApi::loadFile, worker, &FileApiWorker::loadFile);
connect( this, &FileApi::loadData, worker, &FileApiWorker::loadData);
connect( this, &FileApi::loadDir, worker, &FileApiWorker::loadDir);
```

Which means my only way of accessing filesystem data is to call a method which emits a signal, which starts the computation on another thread, which eventually emits its own signal at the end to pass on the loaded data.

This is extremely impractical for the use case above, because instead of saying "do thing, load data, wait, keep doing things", I essentially need to say "do thing, load data (with call back 'keep doing things')" and "keep doing things" in another function, which introduces all sorts of brittleness in the code. (and, well, you know, that's exactly the sort of workflow we invented futures for)

**Is there some way I could create a QFuture, or some future-equivalent object (that can be awaited inside a method) from the `loadFile` method, given that `loadFile` always runs on the same worker thread and I am not allowed to create new threads?**

Comment: Have you try with a [QEventLoop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) ?

Comment: You mention "awaited inside a method". Does this mean blocking the event loop is allowed?

Comment: I presume you found https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/04/18/multithreaded-programming-future-promise already?

Comment: Botje: No (I'm assuming `future.result()` doesn't block the event loop), yes (it doesn't help because I'm not allowed to call `QtConcurrent::run`)

Comment: Who said anything about QtConcurrent::run? The library linked at the bottom (https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture) showcases the `observe` function that converts "wait for X signal" into a `QFuture`.

Comment: Oh, right. I did see that library, and it looks like what I need; but I'm not allowed to add any dependencies to the project. I guess I could look at its internals to try and re-implement the parts I need.

Comment: It is just a single header file under an Apache 2.0 license, so you can just copypaste that one file. (with copyright notice, of course)

Comment: @thibsc : I've [used recently](https://github.com/pedrolcl/barcelona-trees/blob/master/barnatrees/src/main.cpp#L31) QEventLoop to orchestrate a series of inter-dependent [asynchronous downloads](https://github.com/pedrolcl/barcelona-trees/blob/master/barnatrees/src/dropboxdownloader.h) from the cloud (a similar scenario to the one exposed by OP), and it is not pretty. Next time, I think I would try asyncfuture ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to create a `QFuture` in Qt is with the undocumented `QFutureInterface` class.

Example code:

```cpp
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( QFutureInterface<FileData> );

// ...

qRegisterMetaType<QFutureInterface<FileData>>();

FileApiWorker* worker = new FileApiWorker();
connect( this, &FileApi::loadFile_signal, worker, &FileApiWorker::loadFile_signal);

// ...

QFuture<FileData> FileApi::loadFile()
{
    QFutureInterface<FileData> futureInterface;
    // IMPORTANT: This line is necessary to be able to wait for the future.
    futureInterface.reportStarted();

    emit loadFile_signal(futureInterface);
    return futureInterface.future();
}

FileApiWorker::loadFile_signal(QFutureInterface<FileData>& futureInterface)
{
    // Do some things
    // ...
    futureInterface.reportResult(...);
    // IMPORTANT: Without this line, future.waitForFinished() never returns.
    futureInterface.reportFinished();
}
```

Some factors to account for:

- The above code uses `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`; which is necessary to be able to pass `QFutureInterface` through a cross-threads signal. To be precise, the `connect` line will fail to compile if `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` isn't included; and the `emit loadFile_signal` line will fail at runtime if  `qRegisterMetaType` isn't called. See [the Qt documentation on metatypes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) for details.
- You can propagate errors, in such a way that calling `loadFile().waitForFinished()` throws on error. To achieve this, you need to create a special-purpose class inheriting `QException`, then call:

  ```cpp
  futureInterface.reportException( MyException(...) );
  futureInterface.reportFinished();
  ```

  in your error path.

  QException is essentially a wrapper for *actual* exceptions that need to be transferred between threads. See [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexception.html) for details.
- While QFutureInterface is stable, and mostly has the same API as QFuture and QFutureWatcher, it's still an undocumented feature, which may surprise contributors coming across it in a shared codebase. The class can be counter-intuitive, and fail silently if you don't respect the points above (which I had to learn through trial and error). This must be stressed in the comments of any shared code using QFutureInterface. The class's source code [can be found here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qfutureinterface.h.html).

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it is strange not to use ready-to-use solutions ([AsyncFuture](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture)) and try to rewrite from scratch.

But I can suggest my own "wheel": lambda as a slot.

```
void FileApi::awaitLoadFile()
{
    qDebug() << "\"await\" thread is" << thread(); 

    emit loadFile("Foo.xxx");

    static bool once = connect(m_worker, &FileApiWorker::loadFileDone, this, // there is possible to avoid the third "this" parameter, but it is important to specify the lifetime of the connection and the receiver context while using lambdas
        [=](QByteArray result)
    {
        qDebug() << "\"comeback-in-place\" thread is" << thread(); // will be the same as "await" thread was

        // do what you need with your result
    },
    Qt::QueuedConnection // do not forget
    );

    qDebug() << "here is an immediate return from the \"await\" slot";
}
```

Useful arcticle [New Signal Slot Syntax - Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: The lambda is not disconnected afterwards. Calling this multiple times would result in the same lambda slot being executed multiple times.

Possible solution would be to use another QObject that is destroyed by the lambda. However that would still not work with parallel calls as the second call could finish before the first and so both lambdas would still be executed.

Comment: @LNJ yes, every awaitLoadFile() call should produce one new lambda call, why this is a problem?